# IBAction button: I want to tap or click once to stop and click or tap again to play again

Tags: swift, swift3, ibaction

```
@IBAction func stopMusic(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if player != nil {
        player.stop()
    } 
    else{ 
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type for `player`? What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: var player: AVAudioPlayer!. I want to be able to tap btn  to stop(which it did). My issue I wanna tap the same btn and resume playing again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
@IBAction func stopMusic(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if var p = player {
        if p.playing {
            p.stop()
        }
        else {
            p = AVAudioPlayer()
            p.prepareToPlay()
            p.play()
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    player = AVAudioPlayer()
}
```

Comment: Didn't work and give me error  and When I replace   p = AVAudioPlayer()

Comment: I replace p = AVAudioPlayer() with just p = player and work  perfect!! thank so much

Comment: can you please select the answer as the accepted answer or vote it up?